# Mathematical books of the Ibn Ezra

Tags: mathematics

I am interested in studying one of the mathematical compositions of the Ibn Ezra. Is anyone familiar with the easiest book that he wrote? Thanks

Comment: Is this on topic? Is this a question about Judaism?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you interested in this?

Comment: Did you try his Wikipedia page?

Comment: The wiki page just has a list of the books that he wrote, but doesn't state their level of difficulty.

Comment: @user12711 Don't you think that depends on what your background is? Similarly, is Masekhet Kiddushin easier or harder than Masekhet Chulin?

Comment: I hear you, but i was thinking that there might be something like meseches megilah...

Comment: @user12711 Is that an easy Masekhet? Why? It's _shorter_ than Kiddushin, but I don't see why it's easier (ignoring the Midrash Aggadata stuck in the middle, which is obviously sui generis).

Comment: Note that since decimal points had not yet been invented and trigonometry was not used, the mathematics books may be more difficult than expected. Examples may be how Rashi analyzes the circular succah or the yam shel Shlomo.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra#Mathematics_and_astronomy) lists the mathematical works as:

[Sefer ha-Ekhad](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/22089), on the peculiarities of the numbers 1–9. 77 pages.

[Sefer ha-Mispar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/42102) or Yesod Mispar, arithmetic. 218 pages. This sefer is also available with a German translation.

Luchot, astronomical tables.

[Sefer ha-Ibbur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21162), on the calendar (ed. Halberstam, 1874).

[Keli ha-Nechoshet](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/20850), on the astrolabe (ed. Edelmann, 1845).

Shalosh She'elot, in answer to three chronological questions of David Narboni.

I am not familiar with the easiest one. You may choose Sefer ha-Ekhad because it is only 77 pages or Sefer ha-Mispar because it has been translated into German.